# JSch hostKey not recognised with Titan SFTP server

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I have an issue with my hostkey verification via JSch. I am using jsch 0.1.53, for my application, and the server I am connecting to is SouthRiverTech's Titan SFTP server.

I have tried generating a keypair with Puttygen, the Titan inbuilt key generator, and also with JSch's inbuilt libraries. The settings I used was RSA, 2048 bits.

The keys created by JSch's inbuilt libraries didn't seem to work. The keys generated by Titan and Puttygen were able to be used with winSCP, but kept giving me a "Reject Hostkey" error with JSch, which should be an issue with the known_hosts file. From what I have found, the known_hosts file should be the same as a public key file, but do tell me if I am wrong. I have set Titan's SFTP version to version 3.

I have the same keys set for the user profile in Titan to find out where the error lies, but to no avail. So far I have yet to find any answers online regarding hostkey issue between JSch and Titan server. This has been giving me a huge headache.

Thank you in advance for any answers you might have. I will try my best to post any information I might have missed out.

EDIT

Further debugging came up with JSchException: UnknownHostKey, followed by the RSA key fingerprint which is used by the server. My client key fingerprint and the server key fingerprint are the same, so why is this happening?

EDIT

Here is my Java code:

```
knownHostsFile = "D:/Keys/test.pub";
privateKey = "D:/Keys/test";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            logger.debug("Starting Upload");
            JSch ssh=new JSch();
            logger.debug("setting hosts - public key");
            ssh.setKnownHosts(knownHostsFile);
            logger.debug("Known hosts set as "+knownHostsFile);
            logger.debug("Setting identity - private key");
            ssh.addIdentity(privateKey);
            logger.debug("identity set");
            try {
            int hostSFTPPort = Integer.parseInt(sftpPort);
            if (!hostUserName.equalsIgnoreCase("no")
                    && !hostPassword.equalsIgnoreCase("no") 
                    && !hostAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                session=ssh.getSession(hostUserName,hostAddress,hostSFTPPort);
                session.setPassword(hostPassword);
            }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ef){
                logger.debug(ef);
            }

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
            config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
            session.setConfig(config);

            logger.debug("Establishing connection...");
            session.connect(120000);
            logger.debug("Connection established.");
            logger.debug("Creating SFTP Channel.");
            channel=session.openChannel("sftp");
            logger.debug("Channel assigned. Connecting channel...");
            channel.connect(120000);
            logger.debug("SFTP Channel created.");
            ChannelSftp sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            logger.debug("connection:"+sftp.isConnected());
            if(sftp.isConnected()) {
                result=Constants.CONNECTION_ONLINE;
            }
            session.disconnect();
            channel.disconnect();
            break;
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            logger.debug(session.getHost());
            logger.debug(session.getHostKey());
            logger.debug("Continuing next loop......");
            throw new JSchException("Session.connect failed",e);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.debug(ex);
            logger.debug("Continuing next loop......");
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Here is a picture of the [Server admin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzPuN.jpg)

Here are the keys I'm having trouble with:

This one does not seem to work with winSCP, and was created in a Linux environment

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA4R+w9rGUsBNJGZxAdnbnA7FMfGGhx3YaLYZtKf9wzKm8NkZeYIuh1fJ6ViX6RmdO55QxQ3PmBIg8QdhQ8m6SizEt9OGeXU2AnEbX/sbj54oHmiFsv24eDFzr7nrDKnrcllByob3LqjeOy5zg27kJt860oh6BAJfimdqVtETSXR1JHfqUIqGxIqsvyKEotX8gjoGkgsW653f18dW5PJKSEvrq6k1SL0bfgSAA0rN4nUq3JzDvowg5ijkOl91/lj8+FEQ7SjWmguTSx5BoI/CTxatCwNZSdzNED/u5A8I3716JuY7MEiTciPdzspGAXS2mHOtsDPkT7z6jvKQ6hWWv/w== test1@10.70.149.178
```

This one works with winSCP, and was created in a Windows environment

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "test"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEA9a1nnbl/DV2Zo7s1IUifeC5suRmdO2ikSb0ToteO9uvA
gg0zYKA1iH52ysC+4Ni86Ceal4oWGl1dXZRKOaWNH6175uDTI1aBfPBvOddBheTeSQAWOkaM
eL5PDDabLkaKZ1GrtbTeEFOD/Kj/dVREhT5/OcEdFmCbHK6+vr2klrtH2xOd/Qeb89BzDFaj
weNER3fFnHVqy5/Nugo3n7CsiBxuK8KOVN4WpDHzrVe/tjAfVZyH8l4XHlR7bWA5rlAGwt0Y
HILQ+lT1PRmi5PiDq7WuP7NF3QhWjG/D1u/5PC/DzxjTOxwwmXfYj2T2OkE/2/tHSdU4geYr
+1ivdASJ5w==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Comment: I needed to use `ssh.addIdentity(hostKey, passkey);` to get over the `JSchException: USERAUTH fail` error. Other than that, the answer below was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing an account key pair with a host key (pair).

The `JSchException` *"reject HostKey: ..."* indicates that the server's public key (aka host key) differs from the public key known by your code or cached in the `known_hosts` file.

The server's host key is typically not generated by PuTTYgen (though it might be possible) and definitely has nothing to do with WinSCP. In PuTTYgen you typically generate an account key pair (which you can then use e.g. in WinSCP).

For details, see my article [Understanding SSH key pairs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys).

The account key pair and host key pair have nothing to do with each other. Whatever you use for the account key, it won't make JSch accept the server's host key. Just forget this idea. It's completely wrong.

You have to provide the correct host key in the `known_hosts` file (or other implementation of the JSch `HostKeyRepository` interface). You cannot use a `.pub` file for the `known_hosts` file. The `known_hosts` file has a set format like:

```
IP_address ssh-rsa public_key
```

You can also use `KnownHosts.add` to set the expected hostkey on runtime.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the quick reply! I believe that I am trying to force both the host key pair and the account key pair to be the same as I am just testing for functionality. In the event that this isn't not what I am doing, is there any way to find the server's public key? I'm trying to connect from a Windows machine to a Windows server, which might be the cause of my issues. This strategy worked before between a Linux server and a Windows machine. I have updated my question with a bit more details.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your concerns. It is a staging environment, so I am just trying to see if the key connection works. After further debugging, I am pretty certain the fingerprints for the key I am using on my client and the key I am using on the server are the same. Why does it give me an error then?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for putting up with me. I have included my code as requested, and included a picture of the server admin console I am using.

Comment: Hi Martin, Do you mean that I can put the following into a fresh file named "known_hosts": `Server_IP_address ssh-rsa public_key(copied from .pub file)` ?
I was not able to use `KnownHosts.add` as it did not seem to be a public function of the API.

Comment: That's might do. But you better show us the format if your `.pub` (it's public key, it's not secret). To access the `.add`, use `JSch.getHostKeyRepository().add`.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for all your time and help. I have added the .pub files, and I'm not entirely sure which one to use, but I will be going with the second one as it seems to work with winSCP.

Comment: You are again confusing account key and host key. WinSCP does not use host key in any of these format. WinSCP caches the host key in Windows registry. Anyway, do you need some help now? Were you able to put the keys to the `known_hosts`?

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry for the late reply. I tried both keys, the first one one is giving me a `JSchEsception: USERAUTH fail` error,while  the second one one is giving me a `JSchEsception: HostKey has been changed` error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm going to try to see if I can implement that `.add` function to grab that host key from the host instead of setting it myself.

Comment: The *"JSchEsception: USERAUTH fail"* means that the host key verification succeeded. Because the error indicates that an authentication failed, what happens only after the host key is successfully verified. So now you have finally a problem with your account key pair.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!